# Angularjs access individual input field from list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have following code in my HTML:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in word_pair" id="list_two">
     <input ng-model="pair" type="text" ng-change="partnerCheck(pair,item.word)">
     <div ng-show="showPartner[pair]" align="right"><i class="ion-checkmark myCheckmark"></i></div>
</ion-item>
```

This looks like following on my screen:

[image]

I have an array in my controller as $scope.enteredSequence, and I want to push value from each of these input boxes into that array i.e. ($scope.enteredSequence=["Patkar", "Janaj", "Stubbi", "Wolle"])

**How can I achieve that?**

My controller is as follows:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.level=1
  $scope.leftList=false
  $scope.enterTextView=false
  $scope.previewView=false
  $scope.promptAction=''
  $scope.promptLevel=''
  $scope.enteredSequence= [];
  $scope.expectedSequece=[]
  $scope.show_stop_button=false
  $scope.show_start_button=true


  $scope.word_pair = [

  {'word':'Nitish', 'pair':'Patkar'},
  {'word':'Mihir', 'pair':'Janaj'},
  {'word':'Jannes', 'pair':'Stubbi'},
  {'word':'Martin', 'pair':'Wolle'}

  ]

  $scope.partnerCheckList = {};
  for(var v in $scope.word_pair){

   $scope.expectedSequece.push($scope.word_pair[v].pair)
   console.log($scope.expectedSequece)

   $scope.partnerCheckList[$scope.word_pair[v].word] = $scope.word_pair[v].pair;
 }

 $scope.showPartner = {};
 $scope.partnerCheck = function(p,i_p){

   $scope.enteredSequence.push(p)
   console.log($scope.enteredSequence)

   if($scope.partnerCheckList[i_p] == p){
     $scope.showPartner[p] = true;
   }
 }

 $scope.start = function(){

  $scope.show_start_button=false
  $scope.leftList=true
  $scope.previewView=true
  $scope.promptLevel='Level: ' + $scope.level

  $scope.counter1=5
  $timeout($scope.startFilling, 5000)
  $scope.onTimeout = function(){

    $scope.counter1--;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

    if($scope.counter1==0){
      $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
    }
  }
  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000); 

}


$scope.startFilling = function(){

  $scope.promptLevel='Level: ' + $scope.level
  $scope.promptAction='Now enter the corresponding pairs in the right column'
  $scope.enterTextView=true
  $scope.previewView=false
  $scope.show_start_button=false
  $scope.show_stop_button=true

  $scope.counter2=20

  $timeout($scope.checkCorrectness, 20000)
  $scope.onTimeout = function(){

    $scope.counter2--;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

    if($scope.counter2==0){
      $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
      $scope.enterTextView=false
      $scope.previewView=false
      $scope.leftList=false
      $scope.show_stop_button=false
      $scope.show_start_button=true
    }
  }
  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
}

$scope.checkCorrectness = function(){

  $scope.ok=true
  $scope.enterTextView=false
  $scope.previewView=true
  $scope.promptAction=''
  $scope.promptLevel=''

  /*dummy check*/
  if($scope.ok){

    $scope.level= $scope.level + 1
    $scope.promptLevel='Level: ' + $scope.level

  }

}

})
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eYKQPM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

With following code modification I was able to get correct $scope.entereddSequence

```
$scope.partnerCheck = function(p,i_p){

   if($scope.partnerCheckList[i_p] == p){
     $scope.showPartner[p] = true;
     $scope.enteredSequence.push(p)
   }
 }
```